# JS очерёдность выполнения кода

Tags: javascript, асинхронность, очередь

Суть проблемы в примере ниже.
При изменении input запускается test(), выполняющий расчёт расстояния от одного адреса до другого, расчёт занимает время, в итоге нарушается очередность работы, должна быть: 1,2,3, а в примере 1,3,2. Как это проще всего победить.

```js
$('input[name=addr]').change(function() {
  console.log('1. значение input изменилось');
  test(function() {
    console.log('2. test() считает расстояние');
  });
  console.log('3. получен ответ от test()');
});

function test(resolve) {
  geocoder = new ymaps.geocode(refineAddress(getFullAddress())).then(function(res) {
    router = new ymaps.route([
      from_address(),
      to_address()
    ]).then(function(route) {

      //набор вычислений, его результат рассчитанный километраж от адрес from_address() до адреса to_address()

      console.log('удалённость: ' + km);
    }, function(error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    });

  }, function(error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  });
  resolve();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="addr" value="0">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('input[name=addr]').change(function() {
  console.log('1. значение input изменилось');
  test(function() { console.log('3. получен ответ от test()'); });
});

function test(resolve) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('2. получен ответ от сервера');
    resolve();
  }, 500);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="addr" value="0">
```

---

```js
$('input[name=addr]').change(function() {
  console.log('1. значение input изменилось');
  test(function() {
    console.log('2. ');
  }, function() {
    console.log('3. ');
  });
});

function test(r1, r2) {
  geocoder = new ymaps.geocode(refineAddress(getFullAddress())).then(function(res) {
    r1();
    router = new ymaps.route([
      from_address(),
      to_address()
    ]).then(function(route) {
      r2();

      //набор вычислений, его результат рассчитанный километраж от адрес from_address() до адреса to_address()

      console.log('удалённость: ' + km);
    }, function(error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    });

  }, function(error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  });
  resolve();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Попробовал ваш вариант, в тестовом виде он работает, а в боевом ничего не поменялось.

Comment: @Зоркий Вы неаккуратно скопировали к себе мой код.

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Кхм, кхм. Вы с такой настойчивостью оставляете этот комментарий, что мне показалось невежливым и далее его игнорировать. Отвечаю. Я не буду рассказывать обо всех нюансах и излагать свои предложения. Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: да, это ваше право, конечно. надеюсь, и у вас нет возражений по поводу моего права вежливо просить вас о том, чтобы вы писали в ответах не только код, но и объяснение. например, о том, что же не так с кодом у автора вопроса.

Comment: @Igor, я обновил код, не могли вы подсказать где я ошибся?

Comment: @Igor, спасибо, за ответ, но снова не работает. Если разместить resolve(); как в примере вне then, происходит ошибка: Uncaught ReferenceError: resolve is not defined. А если внутри then, то ничего не меняется.